# why is while written here with no body?

Tags: c, syntax, while-loop, fgetc

why is the while loop written in this code with no body? what does it do? 
The index and length are both integers and I am reading from a txt file.

```
  // ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
        if (index > LENGTH)
        {
            // consume remainder of alphabetical string
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

            // prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }
```

Comment: The body of the work, is within the `while` statement. It skips alphabet characters from the file.

Comment: *why?* because there's nothing to do in the loop *what does it do?* what the comment says: consume remainder of alphabetical string i.e. read until EOF or a non-alphabetical character found

Comment: It's setting 'c' equal to the contents of the file.  However, from code shown c looks unused other than being set to the value of the file.

Comment: The fact that this is obvious to old cats doesn't make it a poor quality question. UV'd

Comment: Note: `int c; ....while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));` can simplify to `while (isalpha(c = fgetc(fp)));` as `EOF` is not an alpha and `isalpha(EOF)` is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once it has parsed string of length **LENGTH**, it should ignore all the subsequent characters. Thus, in the body of the while loop:

```
c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF //get c from file pointer and check if it is not EOF
isalpha(c) //and also it is an alphabet because alphabets can only make a word
```

If both conditions are true, keep parsing and ignoring. Moment you encounter a character other than alphabet or just an EOF, reset index and ma be go to next line.

Answer (score 4):

To better understand what's happening, the loop can be rewritten as follows:

```
do {
    c = fgetc(fp);
} while (c != EOF && isalpha(c));
```

It reads a character from the file descriptor, then checks to see if it is either an alphabetic character or EOF.

What the original loop is doing is performing the assignment as a subexpression within the conditional, so that leave the body blank.

Answer (score 2):

> *why is while written here with no body?*

TL;DR - because, it can be written and it serves the desired purpose of the code.

To elaborate, in the code

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));
```

the `&&` operator and its properties are being utilized as part of the controlling expression which serves the purpose of the loop statement. The condition check in `while` remains *TRUE* (1) as long as both the operands of `&&` evaluates to TRUE (1). Once either of them is not *TRUE*, the loop ends.

Just to be clear, till `(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF` **and** `isalpha(c)` evaluates to non-zero value (TRUE), the loop coninues (with an empty body).

The main pages of [`fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) and [`isalpha()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) may be of further help.

Answer (score 1):

This `while` is written with no body, because the action is carried out in the `condition` part of the `while` loop.

If you see the condition of the loop it is:

```
((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c))
```

When first condition - i.e. `(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF` - is evaluated, `c = fgetc(fp)` gets executed, which reads one byte from your file. This byte is first checked if it is `EOF`, which signifies end of file, and if not EOF then it is checked if it is a non-alphabet character.

This action of reading one byte from the file continues either untill either a non-alphabet character is read, or the end of file is reached.

So, what this snippet of code basically does is, whenever `index` becomes more than `LENGTH`, it first reads remaining `alphabets` - without doing anything -, untill a non-alpbabet is read or the end of file is reached. And then it sets`index` to `0`.

That while could be written differently too, so that it would not have an empty body. However, what you have seen is a common `idiom` in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment clearly mentions the purpose of the code.
`// consume remainder of alphabetical string
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));`

Function `fgetc` on each invocation reads a character from the file pointer `fp`. 
On reading it skips the next sequence of alphabets until it reaches something else ex a digit.

Answer (score 0):

So if you read the documentation on [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) it says that it when successful it will return ***the character currently pointed by the internal file position indicator*** or EOF. So that while loop is just assigning c to the next character in the file, checking if its not and `EOF` and making sure its a `alpha character` and it continues doing that until those conditions are not true. That loop could be re-written to:

```
int c = fgetc(fp);
while (c != EOF && isalpha(c))
    c = fgetc(fp);
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` instead of `char`.  For details, read [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/).  As written `while (c != EOF && isalpha(c))
    c = fgetc(fp);` can enter into an infinite loop on platforms where `char` is unsigned.